# Another question about Netflix on Ubuntu

Tags: moonlight, netflix, drm

I know, the issue of Netflix's Watch Instantly not working on Linux has been (sort of) handled by using Wine to run Firefox with Silverlight installed, but that solution isn't working out so well for me. (The Wine window freezes up on attempted loading of Silverlight.)

I have not come to ask for help with this, however.
I have come to ask if anybody has made a "mod" for Moonlight (the open-source equivalent of Silverlight,) to spoof DRM.

I already have the User Agent Switcher add-on spoofing Windows, and the player will load, but it never gets past the part with the blue circle.
I want to know if there is a fork of Moonlight that emulates Silverlight. I don't care whether the DRM is real or spoofed. I'm probably not going to be hosting illegal downloads of Netflix movies anyway (I like Netflix too much to do that ;)

Anyway, I don't need a link, although that would be nice; I just need someone to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

I hate to be a buzz-kill but spoofing DRM is illegal. Have you tried the netflix-desktop app? It's a specialized version of wine made just to run netflix/silverlight.

http://www.iheartubuntu.com/2012/11/ppa-for-netflix-desktop-app.html

Comment: Ehh, I've tried that, it didn't work very well. Thanks for mentioning that, though. P.S., spoofing DRM isn't illegal if you don't get caught! ;) (JK)